# Why won't localhost route to 127.0.0.1 in chrome (OSX)?

Tags: node.js, macos, networking, node-inspector

When I launch a script using node-debug, it attempts to navigate to the URL localhost/debug?port=5858  but does not find a page served there.

If I change the "localhost" to 127.0.0.1 everything works fine.

I can ping localhost and it resolves appropriately to 127.0.0.1

Any ideas?

Comment: node-inspector has this [issue](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/367). I don't have a time to fix it now, but it will be fixed in the near future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

localhost has an IPv6 address (::1) as well as an IPv4 address (127.0.0.1). My guess is that your web server is only serving over IPv4, and chrome is preferring the IPv6 address.

```
$ dscacheutil -q host -a name localhost
name: localhost
ipv6_address: ::1
ipv6_address: fe80:1::1

name: localhost
ip_address: 127.0.0.1
$ netstat -an | grep "[.]80 .*LISTEN"
tcp46      0      0  *.80                   *.*                    LISTEN
```

Note the "tcp46" in the last line -- that means the web server is listening for both TCP/IPv4 and TCP/IPv6 connections, If you run the same command, I suspect you'll see just "tcp4".

I'm not familiar with Node.js, but [this posting](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/nodejs/12avah16tt/binding-to-ipv4-ipv6) seems to imply you can listen on both localhost addresses by using `server.listen(80, '::')`. Alternately, you could create separate listeners for the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, as described [here](http://code.danyork.com/2011/01/20/testing-node-js-with-ipv6-first-step-does-it-work/).

Comment: awesome! I'll give this a shot when I get a chance