# Node.js app works on 127.0.0.1:8080, but does not work on localhost:8080

Tags: node.js, macos, server

I have problem with my Node.js server. I suppose it's not about Node itself, but I'm not sure.

When I start server on port `8080`, accessing it from `localhost:8080` will leave me with blank page, however if I access it from `127.0.0.1:8080` it works perfectly. Normally I would look at hosts file and see if there are some problems. But here is a trick, if I run server on 1337 port (or any other) it will work for both cases, `localhost:1337` and `127.0.0.1:1337`.

**For smart guys** I did a lot of searching out there, but there is no good explanation why this is happening.

Comment: what  `host localhost` command shows ?

Comment: localhost.xx.xx has address 127.0.0.1
localhost.xx.xx has IPv6 address ::1

Comment: try this in /etc/hosts please `127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost`

Comment: do you any log in this server ? i am curious what gets called on localhost:8080

Comment: I created simplest possible node.js server. It has only one function created by http.createServer. There is one console.log when server.js is started, and one within function. Outside one will write in console, and function one is never shown. On the other hand `lsof` command will list node as listener on port `8080`.

Comment: Maybe there is another (old) node process that is listening on 8080, kill all node processes you can see, and start again. Check with `netstat -anpt` to make sure nothing in listening.

Comment: Have you configured node.js to listen for IPv6 as well as IPv4? See [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310909/why-wont-localhost-route-to-127-0-0-1-in-chrome-osx).

Comment: Only one is running on 8080.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, by adding '::' I was able to open it on localhost. However it requires some code changes. Is there other solution, something outside node.js, that will make localhost work?